# man, info pages for a specific flag

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, manpage, info

The man and info pages can be rather long. I only want information about a specific flag for a command.

Example:

`man ls -a`

should return information about the `a` flag for the `ls` command, maybe something like this.

```
   -a, --all
          do not ignore entries starting with .
```